# SSO in iphone, OAuthException

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, facebook, single-sign-on

if I use safari to authorize user with facebook everythig work, but if use native application i have error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1315843200. The current unix time is 1315919174."
   }
}
```

if I tried log out and next log in, I got same access token. How may I resolve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't still holding onto an old token?  Try manually clearing out your NSUserDefaults for those properties and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: before log in i call 
`facebookHelper.delegate = self;
        facebookHelper.facebook.accessToken = nil;
        facebookHelper.facebook.expirationDate = nil;`

Answer (score 1):

If you get OAuthException you need simply to reauthorize.

Also when your app is started you need to make a call to graph API "me" and in case you get exception you need simply to re-authorize, then you proceed with regular workflow of API calls.

You can make your access_token not to expire by requesting offline_access extended permission, but it still might be invalidated.

hope this helps